# Ternary condition on class in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Is there a possibility to use a ternary condition in Sass especially on class object ?
Something which would look like :

```
[class*="fa-caret-"]{
   &:left ? 'top: -45' : 'top: 45';
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you intend that this would do?

Comment: This a bit more complicated to what I wrote. I'd like to detect if the end of the class is "left" and define the attribute top in function of it.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need a ternary operator here, just a slightly different approach - see my answer

Answer (score 14):

It depends on what you want to achieve, but here you have an example of a mixin iterating over a list of elements and a ternary operator for changing a value.

```
$carets: left right;

@each $caret in $carets{
  $symbol: if($caret==left,'-','');
  .fa-caret-#{$caret}{
    top: #{$symbol}45px;
  }
}
```

If you want more elements, or setting properties use a map instead of a list (then, you maybe don't need any ternary operator):

```
$carets: (
  (
    'name': left,
    'value': -45px
  ),
  (
    'name': right,
    'value': 45px
  )
);


@each $caret in $carets{
  .fa-caret-#{map-get($caret, 'name')}{
    top: map-get($caret, 'value');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad naming for a function returning a number. Functions and methods named isX should return boolean.

Comment: Ok, I only hope you understood it was an example and its goal is to answer a concrete question.

Comment: Of course I did, that is probably the goal of every answer here.

Comment: I updated a refactorized answer with better naming convention.

Comment: Naming is kinda better, but the new mixin is pretty much a mess.

Comment: A mixin without repeating code, using ternary operator, with good naming.

Comment: Even though I do not like the first example, the second looks great. Good job.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, I just found out myself just now.

```
$caretTop: 'top: -45';
$caretTop: 'top: 45' !default;
```

Basically, if you don't set the variable before it will default to the first value 'top: 45' if you set it then it will leave it alone.

Comment: Does not have the occasion to test it but it seems nice !

Answer (score 1):

Matching by class attribute selector is not necessary. All you have to do is a simple loop and some interpolation

```
$caret-types: ((left -45px), (right 45px));
@each $caret in  $caret-types{
  $name: nth($caret, 1);
  $offset: nth($caret, 2);
  .fa-caret-#{$name}{
    top: $offset;
  }
}
```

which compiles to

```
.fa-caret-left {
  top: -45px;
}
.fa-caret-right {
  top: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting indeed I migiht have a deeper look into what sass realy allow

Answer (score 0):

@llobet's answer is great, but you could also use a variable.

```
$position: left;

[class*="fa-caret-"]{
   top: if($position == left, -45, 45);
}

$position: right;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would update it with my version for SASS syntax. The quotes have to be skipped there, and the empty value is not allowed either. If you need an empty string, you have to use `()` syntax:

```
$fontSizes: ("xx": 28, "xl": 20, "lg": 15)
$lineSizes: ("xx": 38, "xl": 25, "lg": 20)
$fontWeights: ("normal": 400, "regular": 400, "semibold": 600, "bold": 700)

=custom-font($fontSizeName, $fontWeightName, $important: false)
  font-size: map-get($fontSizes, $fontSizeName) / 16 + rem if($important==true,!important,())

.title
  +custom-font("xx", "semibold", true)
```